# How do I stop a SSIS SQL task from generating output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package that has to execute a SQL Task for each file in a directory, where the volume of files is very large. This is causing a problem with logging, because every time the SQL task executes it produces the following output:

[image]

Multiply this by hundreds of thousands of files per day, and you get daily logs that are GBs in size. As a temporary solution, we are .rar'ing the files. This is working okay, as the repetitive data compresses well.

But it would be nice if I could prevent this repetitive output all together. **Is there any way to not show the output of a task in a log file unless the task fails?**

We are logging the task via batch like so:

```
dtexec /f "path\to\package\mypackage.dtsx" >> "path\to\log\logfile.log"
```

Comment: Selecting SSIS Logging Level to Performance (not Verbose) would help.

Comment: @Jigar can you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: @Jigar is talking about using Integration Services Catalogs to execute package. It is not in your case. Your case is execute packages in file system. Therefore his tip cannot help you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Wendy

Comment: SSIS Logs are associated with packages and are configured at the package level, not on the deployment method. Check this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/performance/integration-services-ssis-logging

Comment: Adjust common line /Rep[orting] level https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the reporting level to Errors and/or Warnings,
it's the Progress reporting that is annoying you.

### Errors Only

```
dtexec /Reporting E /f "path\to\package\mypackage.dtsx" >> "path\to\log\logfile.log"
```

### Warnings Only

```
dtexec /Reporting W /f "path\to\package\mypackage.dtsx" >> "path\to\log\logfile.log"
```

### Errors and Warnings

```
dtexec /Reporting EW /f "path\to\package\mypackage.dtsx" >> "path\to\log\logfile.log"
```

> E    Errors are reported.
> W    Warnings are reported.

## Reference :

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx

> If the /Reporting option is not specified then the default level is
> E (errors), W (warnings), and P (progress).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flag `/Reporting` with level `N` *(**N** stands for No reporting.)* to prevent any status being reported to the command line console.

There are other levels like **E** for only *Errors*, **W** for only *Warning*. You can pick the choice of output that you would like to see on the console.

*[**Learn more about dtexec Utility this MSDN article.**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx)*

#### Syntax usage:

```
dtexec /f Package.dtsx /Reporting N
```

#### Alternative usage:

```
dtexec /f Package.dtsx /Rep N
```